# Efficiently using LLVM through various platforms

Tags: linux, windows, llvm, packaging

I'm implementing a language using LLVM (C#, .NET Core). I intend this language to have cross-platform compatibility in the sense that its final executable is compiled targeting the local machine, for example Windows 10 x64, or Linux.

To accomplish this, my current strategy is to implement a wrapper CLI utility which consumes my language's compiler library (which uses LLVM), along with packaged LLVM executable for various platforms.

So basically, my CLI tool invokes LLVM's tools automatically (`llc`, `lli`, `lld-link`, etc.).

However, this means that I have to package the LLVM tools compiled for every platform that I want to target (along with some libraries such as `libc` for Unix-like system to ensure version compatibility and consistency?).

So, if I wanted to target the following platforms:

```
ubuntu16, ubuntu14, armv7a, windows x86_64, debian8, ...
```

I'd literally have to somehow acquire their corresponding LLVM compiled executable tools.

The language library, CLI utility, and LLVM tools are compressed ("packaged") into a simple ZIP file.

I'm inclined towards a fully-managed system, so I would like to avoid forcing the users to install the LLVM tools on their local machines.

Should I be packaging the language/compiler onto the standard packaging methods used by corresponding platforms, ex. `.RPM` for Fedora, etc.?

Is there an alternative, efficient (generic?) method to accomplishing this, specially without the need of having to include LLVM tools and libraries along in the package?

How do other cross-platform compilers tackle this problem, or is it only LLVM-specific?

Answer (score 1):

You can statically link whole LLVM into your .NET application and perform all tasks these tools do inside your compiler. This is, actually, what `clang` does - except it uses external linker.